# Looking for a serious alternative to Nicehash... can you please help?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-reward

After the collapse of Nicehash I am trying to find an alternative that will let me mine Monero/XMR algorithm ONLY and get paid in BTC just like Nicehash used to do.

In other words, I don't need any service that will decide for me the coin to mine, but I NEED to be in control of what coin/algo to mine, and that algo must be Monero, as it is very energy-efficient for the kind of rigs I have.

I know that Minergate does this, however I am very reluctant to use them as I have strong suspicions that they steal most of my shares for what I can see.

Do you guys know and could recommend for me such a service?

Thanks so very much for your help!

Comment: Suggest you just mine Monero in a pool and then sell the coins for BTC yourself

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a FULLY AUTOMATED solution like Nicehash used to be.

Comment: Technically questions about service provider availability are off topic on this site by the way

Answer (score 1):

In the exchange, bittrex has the tool where. that when you receive another currency it sells automatically and you get bitcoin.
Bittrex -> Labs -> Auto-Sales

I think she's the best alternative.
https://bittrex.com/Lab/AutoSell

Comment: if someone else please know of any POOL that mines in MOnero and rewards in BTC I'd be very very obliged. Thanks.

Comment: Please stick to English, this is an English site :)

Comment: in my time, I used a dictionary to translate things kkkk. (google trasnlate)